# function undefined even though it is in a different .h file

Tags: c, makefile

I am getting a compile error saying that some functions are undefined. All of these functions are defined in a file called `auxilarity.h` and implemented in `auxilarity.c`

I can't seem to find what I'm missing.

Here is my makefile:

```
assembly: main.o assembler.o hashtable.o  auxilarity.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.o assembler.o hashtable.o -o assembly

auxilarity.o: auxilarity.c  auxilarity.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic auxilarity.c -o auxilarity.o

main.o: main.c assembly.h hash.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.c -o main.o

assembler.o: assembler.c assembly.h auxilarity.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic assembler.c -o assembler.o

hashtable.o: hashtable.c auxilarity.h hash.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic hashtable.c -o hashtable.o
```

and the relevant parts of:

**assembler.c:**

```
#include "assembly.h"
#include "hash.h"
#include "auxilarity.h"

... some code ...

int isArgValid(char *s) {
    char *ns;
    ns = cleanstr(s); /* <-- compiler yells on cleanstr as undefined*/

    if(ns[0] == 'r' && ns[1] >= '0' && ns[1] <= '8' && strlen(ns) == 2) {
        printf("argument %s is a register", s);
        return ARG_REGISTER;
    }
    return 1;

}

...  some code  ...
```

**auxilarity.h:**

```
#ifndef AUXILARITY_H_
#define AUXILARITY_H_

char *cleanstr(char *s);
char *_strdup(char *s);

#endif /* AUXILARITY_H_ */
```

and here is the **auxilarity.c**:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "auxilarity.h"

/*remove leading and following spaces*/
char *cleanstr(char *s) {
        int i, j, k;
        char *copy;
        for(i = 0; s[i] == ' ' && s[i] == '\t'; i++)
            ;
        for(k = i; s[i] != '\0'; k++) {
            if(s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t')
                j =k;
        }

        copy = (char *) malloc(j-i);
        memcpy(copy, s, j-i);
        return copy;
}

char *_strdup(char *s) {
    char *p;

    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}
```

here is the exact error messages I'm getting (It's in French, sorry):

```
hashtable.c:48:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
         ^
hashtable.c:48:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic auxilarity.c -o auxilarity.o
gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.o assembler.o hashtable.o -o assembly
assembler.o: dans la fonction « parseInstruction »:
assembler.c:(.text+0x15): référence indéfinie vers « _strdup »
assembler.o: dans la fonction « isArgValid »:
assembler.c:(.text+0x240): référence indéfinie vers « cleanstr »
hashtable.o: dans la fonction « put »:
hashtable.c:(.text+0x123): référence indéfinie vers « _strdup »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [assembly] Erreur 1
```

I looked all over and I can't find what I'm doing wrong

(I'm also getting some implicit function definition warning for built-in functions like `malloc` despite that I have included the relevant .h files)

Comment: You've shown the declaration of `cleanstr()` and where it is called from; you've not shown where it is defined.  Where is the function body for it — which file?  My guess is that you have accidentally not implemented it yet, or it is in a file you've not compiled and linked with the program.

Comment: And show the error messages, please.

Comment: Which header did you include to declare `malloc()`?  It should be `<stdlib.h>`, but you aren't explicit about that.

Comment: Do not use names (identifiers) starting with `_`. They are reserved for the language/stdlib and implementation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `stdlib.h` is included in `assembly.h`. Also I have updated to include another file and the error messages (excuse my French, I thought it will be better to have the original output rather then a translation that might be a little off)

Comment: Does `hashtable.c` include `assembly.h`?  (I'm OK with localized error messages — especially in French which I can read sufficiently well.  Verbatim is typically good.)  Incidentally, the `void *` cast to `free()` should be superfluous; if it isn't, there's a bigger problem that should be solved by another technique than bludgeoning the compiler with a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
assembly: main.o assembler.o hashtable.o  auxilarity.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.o assembler.o hashtable.o -o assembly
```

You list `auxilarity.o` as a dependency but don't link it in the command line.

You should use macros more:

```
OBJECT = main.o assembler.o hashtable.o auxilarity.o

assembly: ${OBJECT}
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic ${OBJECT} -o $@
```

Using the macro ensures consistency.
You should be using still more macros, for the compiler and most of its options.  But this at least ensures consistency.

---

Actually, all those repeated compilation lines are problematic.  `make` has built-in rules to compile code; use them.

```
CFLAGS  = -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic -Werror
OBJECT  = main.o assembler.o hashtable.o auxilarity.o
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS  =

assembly: ${OBJECT}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECT} -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

auxilarity.o: auxilarity.c  auxilarity.h
main.o:       main.c assembly.h hash.h
assembler.o:  assembler.c assembly.h auxilarity.h
hashtable.o:  hashtable.c auxilarity.h hash.h
```

And even when listing the dependencies, `make` will infer that `main.o` depends on `main.c` so you don't have to list that (though there's no harm done if you do, and completeness suggests it is OK).  You do need to list the headers, though.

And regarding your `undeclared function` warning, make sure you include `<stdlib.h>` in the file.  Since you say `assembler.h` includes `<stdlib.h>` but `hashtable.c` does not include `assembler.h`, you need to put `#include <stdlib.h>` into `hashtable.c`.

Generally, you should include what you use ([IWYU](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use)).  Equally, headers should be self-contained.  There are numerous questions on this topic on SO, so I won't go repeating the answers for them.

Answer (score 1):

In the header file, you **declare** the functions. They are not **defined** in the header (and shouldn't be defined in the header unless they are inline functions, which requires care and C99, which `-ansi` precludes).
The compiler explicitly tells that.

You must define the function (in an other source file for example). Hence something like

Declaration in a .h file (already done)

```
char *cleanstr(char *s);
```

And definition in a .c file

```
char *cleanstr(char *s){ 
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: OP says they have indeed been defined, although they called that "implemented" and misnamed the declaration as "defined".

Comment: You're right. I did suspect a confusion between the two, and therefore an misunderstanding of the compiler error (Not provided so I don't have much clue...)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of my misuse of the terminology (I'm a java programmer most of the time). but as I see you have already concluded from the above comment, I do have a defenition where it should be. Also, I've added the files to indicate where it is to the question